# I'm using Socket to listen for new connections. How do I break out of synchronous Socket.Accept() method? How do I terminate this call?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, blocking

I understand, Socket.Accept() is a blocking call, and there is no timeout property for it (like ReceiveTimeout or SendTimeout). So the thread will just keep waiting indefinitely for a new connection to arrive.

So my questions is, how do I terminate this call after a certain point of time. Should I consider closing the listening Socket from some other thread?

Any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Socket.Poll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to wait for a connection with a timeout. Call it with `SelectMode.SelectRead`, and if it returns `true` there is a connection pending that you can accept without blocking.